# failed to install composer packages in docker container

Tags: php, git, docker, composer-php

Since a few days i cant install composer-packages anymore in my local docker container.
I create new composer.json with `composer init` and try to add a package with `composer require fzaninotto/faker`
Always i get the same error message

```
# composer require fzaninotto/faker
Using version ^1.9 for fzaninotto/faker
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
    Failed to download fzaninotto/faker from dist: The zip extension and unzip command are both missing, skipping.
Your command-line PHP is using multiple ini files. Run `php --ini` to show them.
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.9.1): Cloning fc10d778e4 from cache
    fc10d778e4b84d5bd315dad194661e091d307c6f is gone (history was rewritten?)

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git checkout 'fc10d778e4b84d5bd315dad194661e091d307c6f' -- && git reset --hard 'fc10d778e4b84d5bd315dad194661e091d307c6f' --

  fatal: failed to read object fc10d778e4b84d5bd315dad194661e091d307c6f: Operation not permitted


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

First i guess my ssh key is the problem but i create a new one and add this to github with the same error.
Than i try it with `composer clear` and the problem don't resolved.

The problem come in **EACH** docker container and **EACH** composer packages... so i cant be a problem with single packages or container.

Have anyone an idea that i can do to use composer again?

Comment: The output tells you what happened: `fc10d778e4b84d5bd315dad194661e091d307c6f is gone (history was rewritten?)`. In packagist there's a reference to that commit, but if you got to Github that commit is not in master, it means the history was rewritten. You could try installing the zip extension, this will make composer to fetch from packagist.

Comment: @snahor the commit is already existing. I cant checkout the repository with this commit and i works fine. only composer will not fetch it, and its on **EACH** package (with an other commit but same error message).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using **Docker Desktop (Windows)** and you updated to the latest version 2.2.0.4, then you get this issue.

Downgrade to the 2.2.0.3 and it should work again (at least it did for me).
See: https://forums.docker.com/t/issues-after-upgrading-docker-desktop-to-2-2-0-4/90589

**To downgrade:**

- Uninstall Docker Desktop. Attention: it will delete your containers, save them before if you want to import them back
- Go this page: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/
- Click Download under 2.2.0.3
- Install Docker Desktop with the installer file
- When started it will ask to upgrade to 2.2.0.4, just say "Skip this build"

Comment: Thanks. Not it works. i never beleve that the update is the reasone

Comment: See https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6016 where they are working on fix

Comment: 2.2.0.5 say it fixed "operation not permitted" for read only files

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have enough points to comment on the top answer but the Docker issue was just closed ([like an hour ago!](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6016)) and so simply updating Docker Desktop on Windows should fix it. Worked for me at least. Now I can install Drupal again!